# Python: Sorting texttable by column values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Texttable output:

```
 Label1        |  String                                         | Count  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Addr[24]:      | "Akjalfj "                                      |   15          
Addr[25]:      | "laflklk"                                       |   16     
Addr[26]:      | "amfalkj"                                       |   13 
Addr[27]:      | "asflklal"                                      |   21
```

I would like to sort out the above texttable output based on the count value in descending order.
`Addr[27]: | "asflklal"  |  21` should appear in first line. How do I achieve this in Python?

Comment: You need to pass sorted data to the library that creates your table unless that library allows you to sort the data afterwards. Reading the documentation and/or code of the library will help you.

Comment: Do you have it in CSV file, TEXT file, database, string in code or what ? First find out how to read it. Maybe you could use module `pandas`.

Comment: is this a file or part of python-texttable?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I have formatted the output text file using python texttable

Comment: so it is saved as a text file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes its a text file

Comment: Did you add the rows or where did the come from?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot sort the rows before adding for some reason, you could read it in and sort then write to another file:

```
with open('in.txt', 'r')  as f,open('output.txt','w') as f1:
    lines = f.readlines()
    updated = sorted(lines[2:],key = lambda x: int(x.strip()[-3:]),reverse=True)
    for line in lines[0:2]:
        f1.write(line)
    for line in updated:
        f1.write("{}\n".format(line.strip()))
```

This outputs, it will only work if all lines are in the same format as your example:

```
Label1        |  String                                         | Count
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Addr[27]:      | "asflklal"                                      |   21
Addr[25]:      | "laflklk"                                       |   16
Addr[24]:      | "Akjalfj "                                      |   15
Addr[26]:      | "amfalkj"                                       |   13
```